# Scroll Across A Fixed Div If Window Is Too Small

Tags: html, css, menu, fixed

I have a menu bar coded with css and html only, the bar is fixed at the top but when the screen is resized and you try to scroll through the page on the x-axis, the bar stays in the top left corner, you can scroll through the small window but you can't scroll through the page.

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheets/StyleSheet.css" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>TeraShare</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery/JQuery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/JavaScript.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="Wrapper">
            <div id="Menu">
                <div id="Logo"><a href=""><img src="Pictures/Logo.png" /></a></div>
                <div id="Buttons">
                    <a href="LogIn/"><div class="Button" title="LogIn">LogIn</div></a>
                    <a href="Register/"><div class="Button" title="Register">Register</div></a>
                    <div class="Button" title="Menu">Menu&nbsp;<span class="Triangle"></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Content">
                <div id="Fix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    #Menu
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    min-width:965px;
    height:49px;
    border-bottom:rgba(82,82,82,1);
    box-shadow:0 2px 3px rgba(182, 182, 182, 0.75);
    background-color:rgb(68, 68, 68);
    z-index:100;    
}
```

Comment: Can you show us in practice

Comment: i might be able to make a jdFiddle i'm not sure if your gonna be able to scroll.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ebeBw/

Comment: What is the problem exactly?  What behavior would you like?

Comment: i would like to be able to scroll across the fixed div go to my jsFiddle link and try to scroll i would like to see the other side of my div

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do this without JavaScript

Comment: i am open to any answers i am using javascript on my page anyways could you write an answer?

Comment: Are you using jQuery too?  It's okay if not, it's just simpler if you are

Comment: yes i am it kinda what my whole site is based on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `left` of the fixed div to whatever the scrollLeft value of the window is when it scrolls.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    $("#Menu").css('left', '-' + $(this).scrollLeft() + 'px');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ebeBw/1/